# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 28 path $.message retrofit android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

Please I don't understand the error.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 28 path $.message retrofit android studio Please I need your help

```
package com.sensei.linkrestaurant;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Adapter.MyRestaurantAdapter;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Adapter.RestaurantSliderAdapter;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Common.Common;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Model.EventBus.RestaurantLoadEvent;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Model.Restaurant;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Retrofit.ILinkRestaurantAPI;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Service.PicassoImageLoadingService;
import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import io.paperdb.Paper;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import ss.com.bannerslider.Slider;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityHomeBinding binding;

    TextView txt_user_name, txt_user_phone;

    @BindView(R.id.banner_slider)
    Slider banner_slider;
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_restaurant)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ILinkRestaurantAPI iLinkRestaurantAPI;
    private final CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        compositeDisposable.clear();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarHome.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, 
        R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_link_main2);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, 
        mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txt_user_name = headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_name);
        txt_user_phone = headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_user_phone);

        txt_user_name.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
        txt_user_phone.setText(Common.currentUser.getUserPhone());

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        init();
        initView();
        loadRestaurant();
    }

    private void init() {

        dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).setCancelable(false).build();
        iLinkRestaurantAPI =    RetrofitClient
        .getInstance(Common.API_RESTAURANT_ENDPOINT).create(ILinkRestaurantAPI.class);

        Slider.init(new PicassoImageLoadingService());

    }

    private void initView() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, 
        layoutManager.getOrientation()));

    }


    private void loadRestaurant() {
        dialog.show();


        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization", Common.buildJWT(Common.API_KEY));
        compositeDisposable.add(
                iLinkRestaurantAPI.getRestaurant(headers)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(restaurantModel -> {
                            //Event bus to send local even to set adapter and slider
                            EventBus.getDefault().post(new RestaurantLoadEvent(true, 
                              restaurantModel.getResult()));
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        },
                        throwable ->{
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            EventBus.getDefault().post(new RestaurantLoadEvent(false, 
                            throwable.getMessage()));
                            Toast.makeText(this, "[GET RESTAURANT]"+throwable.getMessage(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        })
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, 
        R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_link_main2);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_log_out){
            signOut();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_nearby){
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, NearbyRestaurantActivity.class));
        } else if(id == R.id.order_history){
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ViewOrderActivity.class));
        } else if(id == R.id.update_information){
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UpdateInfoActivity.class));
        }else if (id == R.id.nav_fav){
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.class));
        }
        return true;

    }

    private void signOut() {
        AlertDialog confirmExit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Sign Out")
                .setMessage("Do you really want to Sign Out")
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Common.currentUser = null;
                        Common.currentRestaurant = null;

                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        Intent intent  = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).create();

        confirmExit.show();

    }

    //Register Event Bus
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Listen Event Bus
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void processRestaurantLoadEvent(RestaurantLoadEvent event) {
        if (event.isSuccess()){
            displayBanner(event.getRestaurantList());
            displayRestaurant(event.getRestaurantList());
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "[RESTAURANT LOAD]" + event.getMessage(), 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void displayRestaurant(List<Restaurant> restaurantList) {
        MyRestaurantAdapter adapter = new MyRestaurantAdapter(this, restaurantList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void displayBanner(List<Restaurant> restaurantList) {
        banner_slider.setAdapter(new RestaurantSliderAdapter(restaurantList));
    }

}
```

> This is the Handles the loadEvent

```
package com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Model.EventBus;


import com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Model.Restaurant;

import java.util.List;

public class RestaurantLoadEvent {
    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurantList;

    public RestaurantLoadEvent() {
    }

    public RestaurantLoadEvent(boolean success, String message) {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public RestaurantLoadEvent(boolean success, List<Restaurant> restaurantList) {
        this.success = success;
        this.restaurantList = restaurantList;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Restaurant> getRestaurantList() {
        return restaurantList;
    }

    public void setRestaurantList(List<Restaurant> restaurantList) {
        this.restaurantList = restaurantList;
    }
}
```

> This is the Restaurant Class

```
package com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Model;

public class Restaurant {
    //Remember all variable names has to be exactly as Json property return from API
    //That will help Gson to parse it correctly

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private Float lat;
    private Float lng;
    private int userOwner;
    private String image;
    private String paymentUrl;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Float getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Float lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Float getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(Float lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public int getUserOwner() {
        return userOwner;
    }

    public void setUserOwner(int userOwner) {
        this.userOwner = userOwner;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getPaymentUrl() {
        return paymentUrl;
    }

    public void setPaymentUrl(String paymentUrl) {
        this.paymentUrl = paymentUrl;
    }
}
```

> This is the Retrofit client for the ILinkRestaurantAPI

```
  @GET("restaurant")
    Observable<RestaurantModel> getRestaurant(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers);
```

> This is the Restaurant model

```
package com.sensei.linkrestaurant.Model;

import java.util.List;

public class RestaurantModel {
    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    private List<Restaurant> result;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Restaurant> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Restaurant> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change Observable to Observable<RestaurantModel[]>
or in anather place you have strign but API give array, check API response and compare with your model (use for example tool Postman)
try and give response if help

[EDIT]
try `private String message[];`

[EDIT2]
in API message it's not String it's Array of object

Comment: Postman returns result without error

And it is already Observable<RestaurantModel> kind sir

Comment: check that postman model is good compare to postman response, if you can, display postman respone here

Comment: copy API respone here https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo and check that your model is good

Comment: {"success":true,"message":[{"id":1,"name":"Restaurant A","address":"2395 Farland Avenue,San
Antonio,TX,78212","phone":"830-445-9369","lat":30.32807,"lng":-81.485451,"userowner":null,"image":"http://ilinkrestaurant-android-app.azurewebsites.net/restaurant_a.jpg","paymentUrl":"http://10.0.2.2:3001/"},{"id":2,"name":"Restaurant
]}

Comment: I did and everything is okay with the model just keeps giving me the same error